# primefaces attribute required in combination with rendered not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, required, rendered-attribute

I would like to use a primefaces outpulabel and an inputtext with the attributes "required" and "rendered".

This combination is working:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Input" for="input" />
<p:inputText id="input" required="true" value="#{myBean.input}"
```

If I click on a save but and nothing was entered I get the estimated error message.

But If I add the "rendered" attribute it does not work anymore;

```
<p:outputLabel value="Input" for="input" rendered="<some option is true>"/>
<p:inputText id="input" required="true" value="#{myBean.input}" rendered="<some option is true>"/>
```

Those elements are wrapped in  tags.
I use primefaces in version 3.5

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What does `it does not work anymore` mean? And what excatly are you using for `<some option is true>`?

Comment: I can click save without anything is entered into the input text, but no message is shown at saving is ok. In the attribute "rendered" I use an if clause to ckeck if the item should be rendered or not (both the same). Rendering is working fine.

Comment: This construct will fail if the `rendered` attribtue evaluates `false` during apply request values phase or validations phase of the form submit request. In other words, the condition you placed in `rendered` attribute is completely wrong. As you didn't show that in SSCCE flavor in your question, it's impossible to give an answer which solves the problem. Please fix your question.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix the question. The label and the inputtext element should only be visible, if some option is true, otherwise not. Also I want to be sure, that the user has to make some input and not leave the inputtext empty. If you like, I post the original source, but I don't think that this will help.